# Cast result of malloc in c library

Tags: c++, c, casting

I was looking at [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and it appears that you should not cast the result in pure c code because it's potentially hides bugs and is redundant. But I also see people saying that c++ requires the cast, so should all c libraries cast the result of malloc because they could realistically be used in a c++ project?

Comment: Why would you use `malloc` in c++? It has a nice `new` keyword.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it appears that you should not cast the result in pure c code because it's potentially hides bugs and is redundant

That is correct.

> shouldn't all c libraries cast the result of malloc because they could realistically be used in a c++ project?

No.  A C library can be used from within a C++ project but still be compiled as C.

Answer (score 5):

No. If it's C code, it should be compiled as C, not as C++, and thus the compiler will allow the implicit cast from `void*` to some other pointer.

It is only when `malloc` is used in C++ code that you need to cast it - and it's in my view a "bad smell" - in other words, a sign that the code should be modernized to use `new` or `vector` or something along those lines. (Of course, there are valid reasons for doing this - for example, you could have some 10k lines of useful code, that you need to plumb into a C++ framework for something else - but typically, the best approach then is to write some C++ bindings that interface to those 10k lines and keep compiling that as C)